# How can I make SVN automatically accept theirs for certain files/file types?

Tags: xml, svn, tortoisesvn

At a company project we use .resx (XML) files to store string translations in our .NET app. We have two branches: a test and a stable branch.

Whenever we merge a .resx file over from the test branch to the stable branch, SVN freaks out and doesn't know what to do with the XML file, and messes it up almost every single time. I want to know if there's a way to just `accept-theirs` these files (or even this entire file type, as this is the only thing we use them for) every time they are merged, because we just want to use the one from the test branch every time anyways.

We use TortoiseSVN, and I though I could set up some kind of rule for it there, maybe in the "Advanced merge settings" in the Merge Tool section, however I just don't know how to do that.

Comment: I recommend that a human being always reviews the changes. Even if they will take "theirs" in 99.9% of the cases that remaining 0.1% is the reason there has to be a human involved.

Comment: We always make new changes to the test branch and then merge them to the stable branch, so there are no untested changes. These are also just strings, so there's really no harm that could be done.